# How to bypass ODOO security rules given by administrator?

Tags: security, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

how to view settings which is not allowed to view for users in ODOO, for studying purpose only i.e., how to bypass the access rights

Comment: You can't do that

Answer (score 1):

Simply you cannot this is a framework develloped with qualified community.

If you can do that why use it at all!!!? The security in odoo is one of the things that make odoo, in the top framewoK league.