# Disable or Bypass login of odoo when trying to hit from external application

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I am trying to open odoo url from my hosted application but its redirecting to login screen. As user is already logged in to my application logically user should not be redirected to  login screen again...How can I bypass  this security check of odoo???

Thanks In advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bypass ODOO security rules given by administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193832/how-to-bypass-odoo-security-rules-given-by-administrator)

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think what you are trying to achieve is to authenticate your user's odoo session automatically if that user is already authenticated in your non-odoo application. To achieve that, you can implement your application such that, on authentication of a user, your backend will authenticate a session in odoo with corresponding user, and set `session_id` cookie of user's browser to that authenticated session_id. I guess that may be achievable if both application are served under same domain with reverse proxying using nginx or apache, as other's already commented, there is no way you can totally disable or bypass authentication of odoo itself, as this is a well developed business related software, and that will just defeat it's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to bypass the security of odoo. These changes are required in these two files
`

```
**server/odoo/http.py**
line number 406 in odoo 12
 def validate_csrf(self, csrf):
        # if not csrf:
        #     return False
        #
        # try:
        #     hm, _, max_ts = str(csrf).rpartition('o')
        # except UnicodeEncodeError:
        #     return False
        #
        # if max_ts:
        #     try:
        #         if int(max_ts) < int(time.time()):
        #             return False
        #     except ValueError:
        #         return False
        #
        # token = self.session.sid
        #
        # msg = '%s%s' % (token, max_ts)
        # secret = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('database.secret')
        # assert secret, "CSRF protection requires a configured database secret"
        # hm_expected = hmac.new(secret.encode('ascii'), msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
        # return consteq(hm, hm_expected)
        return True

def setup_session(self, httprequest):
        explicit_session = True
        # recover or create session
        # session_gc(self.session_store)
        #
        # sid = httprequest.args.get('session_id')
        # explicit_session = True
        # if not sid:
        #     sid =  httprequest.headers.get("X-Openerp-Session-Id")
        # if not sid:
        #     sid = httprequest.cookies.get('session_id')
        #     explicit_session = False
        # if sid is None:
        #     httprequest.session = self.session_store.new()
        # else:
        #     httprequest.session = self.session_store.get(sid)
        httprequest.session = self.session_store.new()
        httprequest.session.uid =2
        httprequest.session.login = 'root'
        httprequest.session.db = 'odoo'
        httprequest.session.sid = '7aa5500f30365aead781465ec08bbb03c3a5024b'
        return explicit_session

line number 1348

def setup_session(self, httprequest):
        explicit_session = True
        # recover or create session
        # session_gc(self.session_store)
        #
        # sid = httprequest.args.get('session_id')
        # explicit_session = True
        # if not sid:
        #     sid =  httprequest.headers.get("X-Openerp-Session-Id")
        # if not sid:
        #     sid = httprequest.cookies.get('session_id')
        #     explicit_session = False
        # if sid is None:
        #     httprequest.session = self.session_store.new()
        # else:
        #     httprequest.session = self.session_store.get(sid)
        httprequest.session = self.session_store.new()
        httprequest.session.uid =2
        httprequest.session.login = 'root'
        httprequest.session.db = 'odoo'
        httprequest.session.sid = '7aa5500f30365aead781465ec08bbb03c3a5024b'
        return explicit_session


**server/odoo/service/security.py**
line number 18
def check_session(session, env):
    # self = env['res.users'].browse(session.uid)
    # expected = self._compute_session_token(session.sid)
    # if expected and odoo.tools.misc.consteq(expected, session.session_token):
    #     return True
    # self._invalidate_session_cache()
return True
```